# IFNULL in NHibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate, null

Right now I have something like this in NHibernate:

```
Expression.Like(property, value, MatchMode.Anywhere)
```

and that generates SQL like:

```
property LIKE '%value%'
```

which is fine for that case.  In another case, I want the SQL:

```
IFNULL(property LIKE '%value%', 0)
```

but I don't see any example in the manual that refers to IFNULL, nor can I even find any plain-ol' API docs.

I found Expression.Sql(), but only the one example in the manual, and it scares me a little both to use something for which I haven't seen any real docs, and to be doing anything with SQL myself when I'm using NHibernate to try to get away from that.

Is there a better way to do IFNULL in NHibernate than Expression.Sql()?

Comment: As a side note you should use coalesce as that is ansi standard whilst isnull is t-sql specific.

Comment: I don't know what "t-sql" is but I'll make a note of that.  Thanks!

Comment: t-sql is transact sql, is the particular dialect of sql used by microsoft sql server and sybase.

Comment: Ah, I've never used either of those databases.  Also, the "Microsoft Transact-SQL" reference doesn't list an IFNULL function at all.  I think you mistook IFNULL for ISNULL.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming this is in a WHERE clause, at which point `IFNULL(property LIKE '%value%', 0)` is not valid SQL since LIKE evaluates to true or false, and 0 is neither of those.

I suspect you actually want `property LIKE '%value%' OR property IS NULL`?

If this is the case:

```
.Add(
    Expression.Disjunction()
    .Add(Expression.Like(property, value, MatchMode.Anywhere))
    .Add(Expression.IsNull(property))
)
```

Comment: I think you meant AND NOT NULL instead of OR NULL, but I was able to use this strategy to make an Expression that works for me.

Comment: If you didn't want nulls why would you even use coalesce anyway? You could just use the LIKE since that would never match a null and thus x LIKE 'value' AND x IS NOT NULL is exactly the same as if you remove the IS NOT NULL.

Comment: Because "COALESCE(x LIKE y, false)" looks a lot simpler and more direct to me than "(x LIKE y) AND (x IS NOT NULL)".  And simply using "x LIKE y" gives NULL when x=NULL which is completely different -- in particular, when used inside an Expression.Not(), NULL is still NULL.

Comment: Would that just be; NOT (x LIKE 'y') AND x IS NOT NULL ? If x is null then the lhs would be null, and the rhs false, null and false == false. Otherwise the lhs would be true or false, and the rhs would be true.

Answer (score 0):

It isnt a answer per se but i suggest you to look for `COALESCE()`. [Here](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/coalesce-vs-isnull-sql.html) you can see why.

Comment: That's neat, and if I ever want to use ISNULL (which I'm not, here), I'll be sure to check it out.  :-)